# SSD: Does frequent powercycling / high number of power on count reduce lifetime?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sleep, power-management

Frequent power cycling on rotating HDDs decreases lifetime, I know that.

Since on SSDs there are no moving parts I would expect that powercylcing them wouldn't reduce their lifetime. So you can easily put your PC to sleep without worrying about your drive dying earlier.

However CrystalDisk info shows be for a SanDisk SSD (S-ATA) and a WD SN750 (NVMe) Power On Count number which is increased every time after PC wakes up from sleep. So I wonder if it does impact drive life time. If this attribute wouldn't affect drive lifetime then why should it be recorded?

[image]

PS: I know putting PC into StandBy is nowadays on Windows by default hybrid standby which means writing a hibernation file to disk. On hybrid sleep a smaller hibernation file is saved than on normal hibernation mode, see https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/01793f78-aedd-4f9d-941f-e410b5bf2121/what-data-is-not-saved-in-emergency-hinbernation-file-hybride-standby-mode
On rotational disks you notice that because resuming with cut power, so from emergency hibernation file takes significantly longer than from a normal/full hibernation file. So putting you PC to (hybride) sleep increases lifetime writes / TB written and thus puts a additional wear on your drive and reducing lifetime thus a little bit. However in this question I focus solely on the power on count if this will impact/reduce lifetime of your SSD.

Comment: Most SSDs have an own internal power management. Therefore I would assume that your SSD enters a sleep state more often that you put your PC into stand-by mode. For an SSD that works this way the only difference is that on a PC standby the SSD is really powered-off. Negative effects could only arise if the on-time is too short to perform the "SSD idle operations" (reorganizing the internal flash, self-diagnostic like reading all sectors for finding potential problems).

Answer (score 2):

> If this attribute wouldn't affect drive lifetime then why should it be recorded?

Because it can. SSDs use the same SMART reporting as HDDs do. The field for power on count is there (maybe even mandatory, I don't know). There's no harm in using it.

> So putting you PC to (hybride) sleep increases lifetime writes / TB written and thus puts a additional wear on your drive and reducing lifetime thus a little bit.

Don't worry about it. Modern flash and wear leveling techniques are so good that even QLC drives are good enough for majority of users.

Answer (score 0):

Power on-off cycllng can have a definite adverse effect upon electronic
equipment reliability. The degree to which reliability is affected depends
upon several factors such as part quality, cyclic rate, temperature affects,
environment, and transient suppression capabilities of the system.

Experiments have shown that power-on is the most dangerous operation for
electronic equipment, when power goes from zero to 100 percent.
For this reason, the favorite time for finding out a hardware problem is
often when turning on the computer.

That said, the equipment is designed to withstand many power cycles per day
for years.
As long as power is not failing every few minutes, you do not have to worry about
turning on-off your equipment.

However, as power fluctuation can be destructive, adding at least a surge-protector
is advised, or even a UPS (Uninterrupted Power Supply).

Comment: But those effects usually should be limited to the PSU? (assuming you have a well designed, non-defect PSU).

Comment: @Robert: True, but a PSU is specifically designed for that (how well depends on quality).