# Does "Power On Count of SSD" affect its lifespan?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I ran CrystalDiskInfo on my new HP EliteBook 845 G8 laptop, found Power On Count of SSD is extremely large, as the following shows

[image]

After a lot googling, it looks due to Windows 10 modern standby, as [this post](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-T400-T500-and-newer-T-series-Laptops/Help-10K-SSD-power-cycling-count-for-T14S-AMD/m-p/5035047?page=1#5125356) talked.

So, my question is, does Power On Count of SSD affect its lifespan?

I know, there is [a post](https://superuser.com/questions/1631693/ssd-does-frequent-powercycling-high-number-of-power-on-count-reduce-lifetime) about that. But the number of Power On Count is way less than my number. And there is no accepted answer in that post.

Could anyone bring some convincable information of this question？

Comment: Just a guess: I think this number comes from the age of traditional hard disks, where in fact, this could affect the lifespan.

Comment: @PMF, very possibly, but don't know how it will affect the lifespan of the SSD.

Comment: The power-on count and power-on hours do not *"affect the lifespan"* of the drive.  They are statistics that help *quantify*, i.e.  measure, the lifespan in more meaningful terms than calendar time.

Comment: Maybe, but better we could have clarifications from SSD vendors